# How to run a cron job as a specific user?

Tags: 14.04, server, automation

I have a couple of commands I want executed after the machine boots up. A user shouldn't have to log in or anything for them to run.

I found [this great answer suggesting crontab](https://askubuntu.com/a/816/39694) with the `@reboot` keyword, however this will run as root, and I'd like to run as a specific user created for these "services" (not actual system services).

What are someways to achieve that same effect with any given user?

Comment: Try to run '$ su [username][command]'

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could create a crontab for the specific user like so:

```
crontab -u <username> -e
```

Or more simply, you could just run `crontab -e` when logged in as that user.

Alternatively, you could prefix your command in your (root) crontab with `sudo -u <username>` to run the command as the specified user.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to get it working with those. But I do now see that I can create a crontab for anyone. The commands wound up running fine as root with sudo. I didn't know I could use sudo there (was expecting it to fail waiting for a password).

Comment: @Louis `sudo` does not require a password when you invoke it as root. Basically you're not gaining permissions but giving them up.

Comment: @kraxor  - you could just run crontab -e when logged in as that user. i think this is not correct .

Comment: Could the specific user has root permissions during the run?